# deallocating array of struct pointers in c implementation of priority queue

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, heap, free

I have an issue freeing my array of struct pointers for a priority queue that I am implementing. I create two dynamic arrays of node pointers with a fixed size from client c program. The array *heapMap* contains node pointers that map to each created node with a specific ID integer value and the array *heap* is the heap array that contains the nodes with respect to their current values.

Everything seems to work, however, my pq_free function seems to cause errors or doesn't properly deallocate the arrays. Any help would be appreciated

Structures

```
typedef struct node_struct{
  int ID;
  double val;
}NODE;

struct pq_struct {
  char heapType;
  int max;
  int inUse;
  NODE ** heap;  //BOTH have a specific capacity
  NODE **heapMap; //array of pointers to each 
};
```

This is the function I use to allocate memory for the structure.

```
    PQ * pq_create(int capacity, int min_heap){


  PQ * newQueue = (PQ*) malloc(sizeof(PQ)); //Allocate memory for a new heap
  newQueue->max = capacity;
  newQueue->inUse = 0;
  int inUse = 1;//1 in use by default, the 0th point in the array is left alone intentionally

  //If min_heap == 0, it it is a max heap, any other value is a min heap.
  if(min_heap != 0){
    newQueue->heapType = 'm';
  }else{
    newQueue->heapType = 'M';
  }

  //Allocate memory for heapMap and heap..

  newQueue->heap = (NODE**) malloc(sizeof(NODE*)*capacity); //array of nodes, the heap


  newQueue->heapMap = (NODE**) malloc(sizeof(NODE*) * capacity);//array of node pointers, the HEAPMAP
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < capacity + 1;i++) {
      newQueue->heapMap[i] = NULL;
  }

  //return PQ pointer

  return newQueue;
}
```

This is my pq_free function that doesn't seem to work properly. Thanks for help in advance.

```
 void pq_free(PQ * pq){
 //free all nodes

 NODE * temp;
 NODE ** temp2;
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < pq->inUse; i++) {
     if (pq->heapMap[i] != NULL) {
         temp = pq->heapMap[i];
         free(temp);

     }
 }
 //pq->heapMap = NULL;
 free(pq->heap);
 free(pq->heapMap);
 free(pq);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was once railed on this site for doing this, I feel obligated to do the same to you. You shouldn't cast malloc because it is automatically cast to the assigned data type and can lead to some bad situations.

Other than that how are the individual nodes allocated? What errors specifically are given? I think you are also walking off your heapMap as you allocate capacity but iterate over capacity + 1 elements.